# Existence of a map $F: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$

Tags: real-analysis

Does there exist a map $F: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ and an infinite subset $D\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ such that
$$
\forall E>0 \quad \exists \delta>0: \quad \forall x,y\in D \quad (0<\|x-y\|<\delta \Rightarrow \|F(x)-F(y)\|>E) ?
$$

As I see, $D$ cannot be open. But what about only infinite $D$ ?

Comment: When you say "map" do you mean any function, or continuous functions or something similar? (The term map is sometimes used for "tame" functions)

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Let $D$ be any infinite set which has a *minimal* distance $d$ among its points, and let $F$ be arbitrary. Then, for any $\delta<d$ we have *no* $x,y$ pairs in $D$ such that $0<\|x-y\|<\delta$, so the implication is true.